# Can I display video from a Canon PowerShot Pro 1 on a raspberry pi?

Tags: camera, streaming-video

I am looking to make a photo booth using a Canon PowerShot Pro 1 and a Raspberry Pi. I am able to communicate with the camera over usb using gphoto2 for taking photos. I still havent figured out how to stream video from the camera. Ideally I would be able to show the contents of the viewfinder on the pi. I dont need to record any video. Is it possible to show this on the pi?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Pi's CPU is not powerful enough for realtime video decoding. However, the GPU is (e.g. [omxplayer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/video/README.md), which uses the GPU, is quite happy playing back 1080p video). So, firstly the trick will be figuring out what format your Canon camera can provide video from the viewfinder in (assuming it can do this at all). If it's H.264, great, you can just throw that at omxplayer. If it's MPEG2 you'll need to buy an [MPEG2 decoder license key](http://swag.raspberrypi.org/products/mpeg-2-license-key) in order to get the GPU to handle the decoding. If it's something else ... erm ... no idea.

Then there's the question of how the viewfinder stream is delivered from the camera (network socket? file handle? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with gphoto2) and how to get that stream to omxplayer. Unfortunately I can't shed much light on that bit!